# Insert the data in the sqlite3 database

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I need some help, I have created a database with columns to allowed me to store the list of strings in a database. Now I would like to insert the data in a database, but it will only store the data in the buttons table but not for the programs table.

when I try this:

```
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE programs(channel TEXT, title TEXT, start_date TIMESTAMP, stop_date TIMESTAMP, button_id TEXT, description TEXT)')
con.commit()


for program in channel.findall('programme'):
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO programs(channel, title, start_date, stop_date)" + " VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", [channel_name, title, start_time, stop_time])

programs_id = list()

for elem in program_button:
    programs_id.append(elem.getId())
programs_id = map(str, programs_id)

#store the id and width of buttons in a database
for ids, width in zip(programs_id, program_width):
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO buttons(button_ids, button_width)" + " VALUES(?, ?)", [ids, width])
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO programs(button_id)" + " VALUES(?)", [ids])
con.commit()
cur.close()
```

I want to insert the data `ids` in the column `button_id` in the programs table, but when I try it nothing has happens.

Can you please help me how I can insert the data in the programs table?

**EDIT: When I try this:**

```
for ids, width in zip(programs_id, program_width):
    cur.execute("UPDATE programs SET button_id = ? WHERE title=?", ([ids, title]))
```

Here it will store the data in the wrong rows.

```
#yields:    
#channel | title        | start_date  | stop_date  | button_id | description
###########################################################################
#BBC One     | Tomorrow's Food | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3003   | blank
#BBC One     | BBC News at Ten | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3056   | blank
#BBC One     | South E Today   | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3125   | blank
#BBC One     | A Question of S | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3006   | blank
#BBC One     | Film 2016       | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3007   | blank
```

It should be like this:

```
#yields:    
#channel | title        | start_date  | stop_date  | button_id | description
###########################################################################
#BBC One     | Tomorrow's Food | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3003   | blank
#BBC One     | BBC News at Ten | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3004   | blank
#BBC One     | South E Today   | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3005   | blank
#BBC One     | A Question of S | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3006   | blank
#BBC One     | Film 2016       | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| 3007   | blank
```

Answer (score 1):

Is nothing being inserted into the programs table at all? I think with the current way you are inserting into the programs table you would have rows like this from the first for loop:

```
channel | title  | start_date | stop_date | button_id | description
###########################################################################
chanel1 | title1 | start1     | stop1     | blank     | blank
```

And from your second loop you would have rows like this:

```
channel | title | start_date | stop_date | button_id | description
###########################################################################
blank   | blank | blank      | blank     | id1       | blank
```

I think you may need to insert the button_id and channel info etc. in the same SQL statement like this:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO programs(channel, title, start_date, stop_date, button_id)" + 
    " VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", [channel_name, title, start_time, stop_time, button_id])
```

Or you could update the fields with an update statement like this in your second loop:

```
cur.execute("UPDATE programs SET button_id = ? WHERE title=?",
    (button_id, title,) )
```

Where the title (or other field) is your primary key for the table, or insert the button_id first and complete this update statement:

```
cur.execute("UPDATE programs SET channel=?, title=?, start_date=?, end_date = ? WHERE button_id = ?",
    (channel, title, start_date, end_date, button_id,) )
```

An example to expand on your comment:

```
channel_name = 'PBS'
title = 'planet earth'
start_date = '2015-01-01'
end_date = '2016-01-01'

cur.execute("INSERT INTO programs(channel, title, start_date, stop_date)" + 
    " VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", [channel_name, title, start_time, stop_time] )

#yields:    
#channel | title        | start_date  | stop_date  | button_id | description
###########################################################################
#PBS     | planet earth | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| blank     | blank

button_id = '1'
title = 'planet earth'

cur.execute("UPDATE programs SET button_id = ? WHERE title=?",
    (button_id, title,) )

#yields:    
#channel | title        | start_date  | stop_date  | button_id | description
###########################################################################
#PBS     | planet earth | '2015-01-01'|'2016-01-01'| '1'       | blank
```

I think the problem right now is you aren't using button_ids that are linked to your programs yet. Maybe using program.getChannel, etc. would work so that you can insert button_id at the same time. Otherwise from the code posted I am not sure how to 'link' your program to the button id. Does the elem in program_button have a get channel or get title attribute? If so the above could change to:

```
cur.execute("UPDATE programs SET button_id = ? WHERE title=?",
    (button_id, elem.getTitle(),) )
```

Or something along those lines.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, but when I try this `cur.execute("UPDATE programs SET button_id=?", ([ids]))`, it will update the same data in each row in the database so how i can update the data in the table without the repeating as i am using them in the loop?

Comment: Look at the bottom of the answer, I changed it to reflect your comment. The main problem is a 'WHERE' clause in the update SQL command I think.

Comment: I don't think you understand i am trying to say. Please see on the bottom of my question that I have edited so you will see the data `button_id` have been updated in the wrong rows which it should have been updated in each row without get mess it up.

Comment: In the loop with the ' zip(...)' where is the title value changing in the insertion during the loop? I cannot follow how your button_id variable is linked to the  title from the information you have provided. Does your data at any point have the format channel_list = ['channel_name', 'title', 'button_id',...] ? Or can you produce a list like that? Otherwise I am not sure how to properly reference the button_id to a particular title/ the proper row.